# Spring MVC: HTTP Status 404, No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BugzillaReport/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I am struggling to bring up my application. But i am getting the HTTP status 404 with console warning as "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BugzillaReport/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'"

I check many people answers, but still, I am not able to fix this. Please lend your hands.

About the application: to upload an xml, and create another xml in the backend and give an option for the user to download new XML. (application is not complete though)

below are the contents of all my files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BugzillaReport</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">    


<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.bugzillareport" />

<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>  

</beans>
```

BugzillaReportController

```
package com.test.bugzillareport.controller;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dellemc.bugzillareport.service.DeferralReportService;

@Controller
public class BugzillaReportController {

    @Resource
    DeferralReportService deferralReportService;

    private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY ="/inputXmls";  

    @RequestMapping("uploadform")  
    public ModelAndView uploadForm(){
        return new ModelAndView("uploadform");    
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView saveimage( @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file,  
           HttpSession session) throws Exception{  

    ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();  
    String path = context.getRealPath(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);  
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

    System.out.println(path+" "+fileName);        

    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();  
    BufferedOutputStream stream =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(  
         new File(path + File.separator + fileName)));  
    stream.write(bytes);  
    stream.flush();  
    stream.close();

    deferralReportService.createDeferralXml(path, fileName);

    return new ModelAndView("uploadform","filesuccess","File successfully saved!");  
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Image File Upload</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>File Upload Example - JavaTpoint</h1>

<h3 style="color:red">${filesuccess}</h3>
<form:form method="post" action="savefile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><label for="image">Choose Image</label></p>
<p><input name="file" id="fileToUpload" type="file" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to web.xml `contextConfigLocation` and `ContextLoaderListener`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>BugzillaReport</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I added the following lines:

   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>




Still its showing "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BugzillaReport/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'" when giving the url 

http://localhost:8080/BugzillaReport/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the mapping of the servlet with the URI. You have mapped everything at `/` whereas it should be mapped at `/BugzillaReport`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>BugzillaReport</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/BugzillaReport</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```